# two separate required contact form 7 checkboxes but only one must be checked

Tags: forms, checkbox, contacts

Please help me to validate two separate required contact form 7 checkboxes but only one must be checked.

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you post some code?

Comment: I'm confused, two are required, but only one must be checked?

Comment: How bout replacing the checkboxes with radio buttons in a groupbox, that way, only one can be selected at a time

Comment: Sorry, I mean one of them must be selected. Thanks

Comment: I can't replace checkboxes with radio buttons as checboxes are in use with huge data. Thanks

Comment: these are the codes


<p>E-mailadres*<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>
<p>[checkbox checkbox-199 "Yes, my name and address may be publicly visible"]</p>
<p>[checkbox checkbox-249 "Yes, I would like to receive newsletter."]</p>